# Java Looping Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I need help with writing a Java program. I will explain what I need to do, and then explain what I have/what I am troubled with --

I need to write a program that is passed a number of values through a scanner. The number of values passed in is a pre-determined variable. For this explanation, let's call the predetermined number of passed in numbers "n".

So, for n numbers, I must return the maximum number of values within another pre-determined boundary. I will call this boundary b.

For example:
If `n = 5`, then there are five lines of input, and if `b = 3`, then the numbers can differ by no more than three.

If these 5 lines of input are -

```
1
6
4
3
1
```

Then, the output must be `4`.

Comment: `If these 6 lines of input are - 1 6 4 3 1` -> But aren't these 5 numbers? Moreover, the question is still unclear, `6 4 3` also fall in range, for `b = 3`, if I understood correctly.

Comment: An algorithm has nothing at all to do with programming. Start with pen and paper, how would you do this?

Comment: What is the boundary calculated against? The first input? the last valid one so far?

Comment: I don't really know, the question is confusing; that's all I'm given, However, I suppose it's the last valid one. The sample input, and output however is given to me, so that is not wrong.

Comment: @blazs no: 6 - 1 = 5, and 5 > 3.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. `1 6 4 3 1` 1 and 6 have a difference greater than 3. (6,4), (4,3), (3,1) don't. Is that how you get 4 numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you know how to read the elements from the standard input into an array, and just focus on the algorithm itself. (Assuming you gave the problem an honest shot, you already wrote the code that reads the data from the standard output, and can easily use the method I provided below.)

Sort the array (ascending order) so that "similar" elements are close together. Then for each element count how many elements "above" it are within `b`; because the array is sorted, these are all elements that are at most `b` away from the element. Return the maximum count.

Here's the code.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {
    public static int count(int[] arr, int b) {
        int maxCount = 0, curCount = 0;
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
            curCount = 0;
            for (int j = i; j < arr.length; ++j) {
                if (arr[j]-arr[i] <= b) {
                    ++curCount;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            maxCount = Math.max(maxCount, curCount);
         }
         return maxCount;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int b = 3;
        int [] arr = {1,6,4,3,1};
        System.out.println("count: " + count(arr, b));
    }
}
```

It prints `count: 4`, as expected.

Comment: @GHat no problem. (Please don't forget to accept the answer you found most helpful.)